Descent of isogenies between p-divisible groups
Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a $p$-divisible group over $K$, which is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\rho: \text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)\rightarrow \text{GL}(T_p\mathcal{G})$ be the associated Galois representation. Let $K_\rho$ denote the subfield of $\bar{K}$ that is fixed by $\text{Ker}(\rho)$.
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a $p$-divisible group over $\bar{K}$. I would like to know why every isogeny $f: \mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ can be defined over $K_\rho$. I saw this statement in the paper
Finiteness of Reductions of Hecke Orbits, Proposition 2.7.
My thought for this is that $f$ can be defined over $K_\rho$ if and only if $T_pf$ is $\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K_\rho)$-equivariant, which is equivalent to show $T_pf=\sigma\circ T_pf$ for any $\sigma\in \text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K_\rho)$, since this Galois groups acting trivially on $T_p\mathcal{G}$. But since $\mathcal{H}$ is defined over $\bar{K}$, I do not know how to proceed.
Any help will be appreciated!

I'm not so familiar with the general story, but I think you can extrapolate from what happens for elliptic curves. For an isogeny to be defined over a field, it's sufficient for its kernel to be defined over that field. Since $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline K/K_\rho)$ acts trivially on $T_p\mathcal G$, it also acts trivially on $\mathcal G[p^n]$ for all $n$, so it acts trivially on $\ker f$. So $\ker f$ is defined over $K_\rho$. Does that sound right?

@Mathmo123 Thanks! And I used the same idea to convince me before. But I just want to make sure that for the isogeny $f: \mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, what we got is a $p$-divisible group $\mathcal{G}/\text{Ker}(f)$ defined over $K_\rho$ and an isomorphism $\mathcal{H}\cong \mathcal{G}/\text{Ker}(f)$ over $\bar{K}$. So seriously, we cannot descend the isogeny to $K_\rho$, but just up to isomorphism over $\bar{K}$. Is this correct?
